# Adjective to best describe sense of helplessness

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am writing a small piece on the current financial and economic crisis, and I am looking for adjectives or short expressions that describe the sense of helplessness that seems to hang over many people these days, like a sense of having no way out from the current difficult economic and political situation.

> 1. People feel **____** in current economic environment.
> 2. Workers think they are **____** because of economic crisis.

Comment: What about "helpless" ?

Comment: or impotent, powerless, or handcuffed? This seems like a good [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/helpless) question.

Comment: This is a thesaurus question; helpless, impotent and powerless are three very good starting points.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What other word can we use in place of "helpless"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33299/what-other-word-can-we-use-in-place-of-helpless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, many adjectives may work in this context I think, I suggest *[lost](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Lost)* with the meaning of:

- unable to find one's way or ascertain one's whereabouts (in a figurative sense).

I guess this is what many people affected by the crisis feel.

Answer (score 0):

I like the word *vulnerable* in your sentences.

Answer (score 0):

> People feel *hopeless* in current economic environment.
>
> Workers [**think they are hopeless**](http://www.devothoughts.com/hopeless-without-hope/), because of economic crisis.

*Hopelessness* is what seems to come the closest to the feeling of having no way out from a difficult situation, as described in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

1)

> a) *Doomed*
>
> b) *Screwed*
>
> c) *Screwed over*
>
> d) *Like they've been given the shaft*
>
> e) *Deceived*
>
> f) *Exploited*

2)

As 1), minus d).

Answer (score 0):

Your *a sense of having no way out* leads me to suggest feeling *trapped* or *cornered* or *stuck* in the current economic environment.

Taking this a little further, you could also use words with more imagery that suggest being stuck in a certain economic “landscape” such as *bogged down* or *mired*, or use *quicksand* as a metaphor for being sucked down further into the ground even as you try to free yourself.

There are still more colorful metaphors that are probably too vulgar for your piece.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **[fragile](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fragile)**

> (Of a person) not strong or sturdy; delicate and vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

In Australia you would be [stonkered](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stonkered).